# Python httpd will listen on used ports without throwing a socket error in windows but not OS X?

Tags: python, cross-platform, google-api, oauth-2.0, apache

This is really a follow-up to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641841/google-api-oauth-httpd-server-conflicts-with-sabnzbd-in-python) about a Python oauth2 BaseHTTPServer conflicting with SABNzbd+.

Basically, I have the following little script (which is used to create a local server listening for Google API oauth2 credentials):

```py
import socket
import BaseHTTPServer
from oauth2client.tools import ClientRedirectServer, ClientRedirectHandler

port_number = 0
host_name = 'localhost'
for port_number in range(8080,10000):
    try:
        httpd = ClientRedirectServer((host_name, port_number),
                                   ClientRedirectHandler)
    except socket.error, e:
        print "socket error: " + str(e)
        pass
    else:
        print "The server is running on: port " + str(port_number)
        print "and host_name " + host_name
        httpd.serve_forever()
        break
```

On OS X, if I run this script twice, I get the expected results:

```
socket error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
The server is running on: port 8081
and host_name localhost
```

However, running the same script from different cmd windows in Win7, I can happily run 3 or 4 servers on the same port (8080) without throwing a socket error:

```
C:\>netstat -abn | Findstr 8080
TCP    127.0.0.1:8080    0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:8080    0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ned Deily's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8772533/684926), Windows doesn't treat multiple sockets the same way other OS's may.

I think that the correct way to do this in windows (and the way that worked for me, and thus the answer I'll choose) is to bind the port to 0 and let Windows handle it by itself. You can then get the used port number back with `sock.getsockname()[1]`.

For anyone else trying to do this with the Google oauth2client.tools, see the code I went with below:

```
import socket
import BaseHTTPServer
from oauth2client.tools import ClientRedirectServer, ClientRedirectHandler

port_number = 0
host_name = 'localhost'
try:
    httpd = ClientRedirectServer((host_name, port_number), ClientRedirectHandler)
except socket.error, e:
    print "socket error: " + str(e)
else:
    print "The server is running on: port " + str(httpd.socket.getsockname()[1])
    print "and host_name " + host_name
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Windows has different semantics from most Unix-y systems about binding multiple sockets to the same address/port.  See, for instance, [this Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue2550) among others.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to be able to have multiple applications hooked to the same endpoint.